# 24-30pin connector for digital picture frame

Tags: voltage, lcd, cables, lvds, panel

Hey all I have 3 27" lcd panels that I will be making digital picture frames out of and I am looking for advice on what i can use in order to use only 1 cable going to the digital picture frame since it will be on the wall. The less wires the better.

Currently I will be purchasing the lcd controller boards for these lcd panels. These boards requires a 12vdc @ 4a to power it.

There is also the lvds cable that connects to the back of the panel itself. This usually has 5/3.3vdc going to it.

So does anyone have any possible suggestions for a type of cable that has enough pins for the lvds and power? I was thinking of using a HDMI-I cable but I am unsure if it could handle the 12vdc @4a? And keep in mind I would like to find a cable that's not very expensive since ill need about 15-25ft of it per digital picture frame.

Comment: There are endless examples of this type of application on the Internet. The minimum cabling for an application like this would be just the mains connection. Put a power supply and micro such as a Raspberry Pi or ASUS Tinker behind the LCD and connect it to your WiFi (or Ethernet if you really want hard wired) for picture data. A 25 ft HDMI or LVDS cable are likely to cost more than the micro you'd use.

Comment: You will be doing well to stuff LVDS over 25 feet of cable at normal sort of display data rates, it is robust, but not THAT robust....